# from haystack.preview.components.file_converters.pypdf import PyPDFToDocuments not able to be recognised

Tags: haystack

While using haystack-ai v2.0 tried to import PyPDFToDocument function using preview package, but it was getting unrecognised by the compiler.

tried to upgrade the library, find the new package but still it was being un-recognised

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue they removed the preview package so instead of doing

`from haystack.preview.components.file_converters.pypdf import PyPDFToDocuments`

do:

`from haystack.components.converters.pypdf import PyPDFToDocument`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).